# CloudWatch Metric filters with default value not making sense

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

I've created a metric filter just to get an idea about how many times a specific log pattern shows up, nothing crazy. `Metric value` is set to 1 and `Default value` is set to 0. Since it's not a high-resolution metric, CloudWatch is aggregating it in a minute period. All good with that.
What I do not understand is the difference between the `Sum` and `Sample Count` statistics. Why `Sum` and `Sample Count` would have different values?

- If we assume that there was no record in the 1-minute interval with the filter pattern, `Sum` would be 0, and `Sample Count` would be 0.
- If we assume that there was at least one record in the 1-minute interval with the filter pattern, `Sum` would be X, and `Sample Count` would be X, where X is greater than 0.

An example:
Let's say I created a metric filter with the pattern "ERROR:", and I set `Metric value` is set to 1 and `Default value` is set to 0.
We have the following logs for three different log streams under the same log group in a specific minute in the timeline:

Log stream 1:

- ERROR: XXXXXXX
- INFO: XXXXXX

Log stream 2:

- INFO: XXXXXX
- INFO: XXXXXX

Log stream 3:

- ERROR: XXXXXXX
- ERROR: XXXXXXX
- ERROR: XXXXXXX

What would be the values for `Sum` and `Sample Count` in your opinion? 4, right!?

I'm expecting some clarity about the usage of the `Default value`